# Perform an "enter keypress" in response to popup

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I would like this popup dismissed when it appears on bootup using an "enter" keypress. Can it be done?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The _Reload_ button is highlighted (tiny green frame around it) and I'd assume hitting ENTER is the same as clicking that Reload button. Doesn't it work? Or do you want to remap the ESC action?

Comment: @PerlDuck I do not want to have to hit the Enter. I want it to occur automatically.

Comment: xdotools may be what I need. I know how to send a return. I need to know how to find out the window id of the popup. --window window
               Send keystrokes to a specific window id. You can use "WINDOW STACK" references like "%1" and "%@" here. If there
               is a window stack, then "%1" is the default, otherwise the current window is used.